# C# ILogger doesn't print console output

Tags: c#, printing, console, ilogger

I've using vs 2019 for a console application(dotnet core 3.1),

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console -Version 3.1.2
```

and this code:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Information)
                .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Information)
                .AddFilter("TestRx.Program", LogLevel.Information)
                .AddConsole();
        });
        ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
        logger.LogInformation("Example log message");
    }
}
```

It doesn't print anything on console, why?

Comment: just tested and it prints: `info: app.Program[0]
      Example log message` as expected...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending on my hosting I could reproduce and it seems you need to dispose the LoggerFactory to flush the console output.

Probably this is a performance feature of newer .NET Core versions. Afaik the older ones directly printed it to console.

```
using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
{
    builder.AddConsole();
});
                
var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
logger.LogInformation("Example log message");
```

You can watch that kind of async nature of logging by creating tons of logs and either wait a bit or quit the program directly:

```
ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    logger.LogInformation("Example log message2");
}
//Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

The sleep will help to flush all logs!

Comment: This is also okay:  
    await Task.Delay(1000);